# Soup.Find with different classes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a question about python, i want to scrape just 1 page with different attribute classes and loop on them, so this is the html code that i needed:

> 'a' : "class: a"
>
> 'div': "class: b"
>
> 'h1' : "class: c"

the page just have one of them, so i try with "else if" and "try" statement but i still don't get it. This code is for one class only:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = csv.reader(open('link.csv'))
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url[0])
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    condition = soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'a'}).get_text()
    print (condition)
```

I have searching for another same problem in this forum but i still got stuck on this.
I hope anyone get help me, Thank you.

Comment: What does that print statement produce?

Comment: Halo bill,, this print a dynamic condition or status

Comment: I mean, can you show us exactly what it prints.

Comment: Now I think I may understand but I'm not sure. Can you try adding print(url) immediately after the for statement, and tell us what you see.

Comment: helo bill, sorry for my bad, but i just want to know how to combine soup.find for 3 attribute and print the text for one  that available

Comment: You can use **find_all()** instead of **find()**, like `soup.find_all('text', attrs={'class': 'a'})`, [read more](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attrs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select all variations of the elements, you could use the `.select()` method along with the three relevant CSS selectors to cover the example that you provided, `a.a, div.b, h1.c`.

If there are any matched elements, you could then grab the first one and get its text:

```
elements = soup.select('a.a, div.b, h1.c')
if elements:
    condition = elements[0].get_text()
    print(condition)
```

Comment: soup select ,, right,, thank you so much josh, but there is still more problem about the class, if the class has space, example = 'div.alang-py prettyprint prettyprinted' , they show nothing i think because the command can't find the class that has space char.

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4
html = """<html>
 <head>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <a class="b"></a>
  <h1 class="c"></h1>
 </body>
</html>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
soup.find_all(class_=['a', 'b', 'c'])
soup.select('.a, .b, .c')
```

In `find()`, `[a, b, c]` means a or b or c

In `select()`, `a, b, c` means a or b or c